# Getting visits, viewed and other site settings from CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Is there anyway to get these values from CSOM or other API?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use graph api to get this:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

For example :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D90')
```